# PFRelation won't save on Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

I am having trouble saving a PFRelation I have this code:

```
//set up the query
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"messageBank"];
    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:name];
    __weak User *weakSelf = self;


    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

        if(error) {

            NSLog(@"No such user");
            handler(NO, error,NO,NO);
        }

        else{

            [weakSelf.friendsRelation addObject:object];
            [weakSelf.friends addObject:object];
            //save in the background
            [weakSelf.messageBank saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if(error) {

                    NSLog(@"Save error");
                }

                else {

                    NSLog(@"no error");
                }
            }];


            handler(YES,nil,NO,NO); //no errors
            //so the friend is added to the friends array, all we need to do is reload the table data don't need to init the array again, the relation is also added to the relation item so don't need to init that again
        }


    }];//end block
```

My code finds the messageBank object fine but it won't save it to the PFRelation friends. It doesn't even attempt to call `[weakSelf.messageBank saveInBackgroundWithBlock...`. weakSelf.messageBank is the local PFObject and weakSelf.friends is it's PFRelation. Anyone have any ideas what could be going wrong here? If I have a PFRelation in class A is it okay to have pointers in that relation to other objects in class A? Does it need to be in a different class? Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: This code is in a class called User?  Is that a PFUser subclass?  And this class has a relation called friendsRelation and a relation called friends, and you'd like to add the found messageBank to both?  What makes you confident that weakSelf.messageBank has any value at all?  (nil there would explain the non-call of the save).  And why not save weakSelf, since that's the object the code changes?  (Also, the weakSelf copy idiom is not required here.  self will do fine and not leak).  Maybe describe the data model and the goal, it should be easy to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaned up version of the code that fetches an object and adds to its relation, and saves it...

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"messageBank"];  // by convention class names should be capital MessageBank, but using yours
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:name];  // better form is self.name assuming it is an attribute of self

[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // see note below about weakSelf
        // assume self is a PFObject subclass with two relations
        // (and generated setters) called friendsRelation and friends
        [self.friendsRelation addObject:object];
        [self.friends addObject:object];

        // notice we save self here.  that's who changed in the two preceding lines
        [self saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if(!error) {
                // success
            } else {
                // handle error
            }
        }];
    } else {
        // handle error
    }
}];
```

Please notice that there's no need to declare a __weak copy of the self pointer  (though, there's no harm in it).  That idiom is used to avoid a retain cycle between self and the block's owner.  You need it only when self is the blocks owner (directly or indirectly).  This isn't the case with parse's completion blocks.